# mod_rewrite all non-files queries in public folder to ../index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I have the following folder logic:

```
.htaccess
index.php
composer.json
(etc. with all processing files)
public/
    .htaccess
    design/
    files/
    (etc. with all static files)
```

With the following in both .htaccess:

```
(.htaccess:)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ public/$1    [L]
(public/.htaccess)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first .htaccess is useful when in development on MAMP and unrequested in production as most website directly serve the public folder.

The reason for this request as opposed to having a `public/index.php` file with `include '../index.php';` is that, for example, Slim uses `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` which would break routing by forcing /public into the url. [One dirty way to solve this](http://blog.mirohristov.com/web/hide-public-from-slim-or-mini2-framework-with-htaccess-and-bugfix/) involves changing a file in the vendor/slim/slim folder, which should be a relatively big forget-it.

Answer (score 0):

(While writing my question, I ended up discover a cozy solution which I would like to share)

```
(.htaccess)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ public/$1    [L]
(public/.htaccess)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

When in development,

- The first .htaccess redirects all calls but index.php to public/
- The second .htaccess is redirects all non files back outside public onto ../index.php,
- The first .htaccess does not do anything.

When in production, only step two and three are done.

This way, dynamic files are strictly separated from static files.